# How to convert componentDidUpdate to useEffect when using prevProps

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, preact

I have a legacy [preact](https://preactjs.com/) (not a typo) component I am trying to refactor to use hooks instead of class based components. I have run into a snag because in the componentDidUpdate it only references `prevProps` and not any specific prop. The legacy life cycle method looks like this:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    addListenersFromProps(this.layer, this.props, {
      filter: ({ prop }) => !prevProps[prop],
    });

    removeListenersFromProps(this.layer, prevProps, {
      filter: ({ prop }) => !this.props[prop],
    });
  }
```

My `useEffect` looks like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    addListenersFromProps(layer, props, {
      filter: ({ prop }) => ?
    });
    removeListenersFromProps(layer, ?, {
      filter: ({ prop }) => ?
    });

  }, [?]);
```

I am not sure what to add to the dependency array for the `useEffect` hook and I am not sure how to call `removeListenersFromProps` as it takes the `prevProps`.

// EDIT:

Based on the first comment, could I do something as simple as this:

```
  
  // track props
  const [_props, setProps] = useState(props);
  

  useEffect(() => {
    addListenersFromProps(layer, props, {
      filter: ({ prop }) =>  !_props[prop],
    });
    removeListenersFromProps(layer, _props, {
      filter: ({ prop }) => !props[prop],
    });

    setProps(props);

  });
```

Comment: useEffect has no way to access the previous props. You will need to keep track of the previous state manually.

Comment: Thanks. I made an edit to propose a solution. Could you do a quick sanity check?

Comment: I would use `useRef` instead of `useState` to avoid re-renders when you update your "previous props". I would also add a dependency array to useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close to solution with your edit. You should use props as callback in useEffect and you should set states inside useEffect with props values. Keep in mind useEffect is not `async` so you need to create `async` functions inside to use my logic

```
const [_props, setProps] = useState(props);
  

  useEffect(() => {
    //Here do your logic but set always to states, if you need create new states
    //If you take states values as argument in your function before setting then it will take naturally previous values
    setProps(props);
  }, [props]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking advice from both comments and answers I decided to do the following:

```
  const prevProps = useRef<MyComponentProps>(props);

  useEffect(() => {
    addListenersFromProps(layer, props, {
      filter: ({ prop }) =>  !prevProps.current[prop],
    });
    removeListenersFromProps(layer, prevProps.current, {
      filter: ({ prop }) => !props[prop],
    });

    // update props
    prevProps.current = props;

  }, [props);
```